# don't allow partially matching document to add to array with $push using updateOne function

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, push

check a document whether it is partially matching (2 or more fields) with existing documents in array('claims') with `$push` / `$addToSet` using `updateOne` and shouldn't allow to be pushed to array

structure is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f50c93dda654e891c903efb"),
    "claims":[
                {
                    "username": "Foo",
                    "claim_id":"12345",
                    "claimed_at":"2020-08-31T17:18:52.818737",
                },
                {
                    "username": "Bar",
                    "claim_id":"54321",
                    "claimed_at":"2020-08-31T17:18:52.818737",
                }
             ]
                
}
```

couldn't use `$addToSet` since other field value like `claimed_at` is not known,
if it was to match single field only like `user_id` it was working,
I was missing something here

```
db.claims.updateOne(
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f50c93dda654e891c903efb"),
    "claims":{"$ne": {"username":"Foo"}}
},
{
   "$push":
               {
                  "claims":
                            {
                                "username": "Foo",
                                "claim_id":"12345",
                                "claimed_at":"2020-09-02T17:08:23.514342",
                            }
                }
})
```

Comment: username "Foo" should be allowed to be added only with another claim_id

Comment: Done, it is working, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `$elemMatch` and `$not`,

```
db.claims.updateOne({
    "_id": ObjectId("5f50c93dda654e891c903efb"),
    claims: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                username: "Foo",
                claim_id: "12345"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$push": {
        "claims": {
            "username": "Foo",
            "claim_id": "12345",
            "claimed_at": "2020-09-02T17:08:23.514342",
        }
    }
})
```